# inconvenientes con el metodo darPasajeroMasSillasAsignadas()

Tags: java

Buen día compañeros tengo algunos problemas con este ejercicio, no llevo mucho tiempo en esto de la programación, este es el enunciado:

Enunciado
Cree el método darPasajeroMasSillasAsignadas, que retorna el pasajero que tiene más sillas asignadas en el avión. En caso de haber varios con el mismo número de sillas asignadas, se retorna el primero.

Nota: tengo un método que me arroja el numero de sillas que tiene asignado un pasajero llamado darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(); no esta en el diagrama de clases ya que es parte del ejercicio pero creo que me sirve para resolver este.

Este es mi código:

```
/**
 * Retorna el pasajero que tiene más sillas asignadas en el avión
 * @return - Pasajero con más sillas asignadas en el avión
 */
public Pasajero darPasajeroMasSillasAsignadas()
{
   Pasajero mayorSillasEjecutivas = null;
   Pasajero mayorSillasEconomicas = null;
   int ejecutivas = 0;
   int economicas = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < SILLAS_EJECUTIVAS; i++){
       if(sillasEjecutivas[i].sillaAsignada()){
           for(int j = 0; j < SILLAS_EJECUTIVAS; j++){
               if(sillasEjecutivas[j].sillaAsignada()){
                   if (sillasEjecutivas[i].darNumero() != sillasEjecutivas[j].darNumero()){
                       if(darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEjecutivas[i].darPasajero()) >= darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEjecutivas[j].darPasajero())){
                          mayorSillasEjecutivas = sillasEjecutivas[i].darPasajero();
                          ejecutivas = darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEjecutivas[i].darPasajero());
                       }

                    }    

               }
           }
       }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < SILLAS_ECONOMICAS; i++){
       if(sillasEconomicas[i].sillaAsignada()){
           for(int j = 0; j < SILLAS_ECONOMICAS; j++){
               if(sillasEconomicas[j].sillaAsignada()){
                   if(sillasEconomicas[i].darNumero() != sillasEconomicas[j].darNumero()){
                      if(darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEconomicas[i].darPasajero()) >= darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEconomicas[j].darPasajero())){
                         mayorSillasEjecutivas = sillasEjecutivas[i].darPasajero();
                         economicas = darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEconomicas[i].darPasajero());
                      }
                   }  
               }
           }
       }

    }
    if(ejecutivas >= economicas ){
        return mayorSillasEjecutivas;
    }
    else{
        return mayorSillasEconomicas;
    }
}
```

El ejercicio me compila pero me arroja el siguiente error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 
java.lang.NullPointerException

este es el diagrama de clases:

https://cupiexamenes.virtual.uniandes.edu.co/media/web/modelos-mundo/15b1c9729a1.jpg

gracias de antemano...

Comment: Debe ser que a la posicion a la que le estas apuntando para ser exacto en la posicion 8 no tienes nada, puede ser que las variables que tienes en los for, tienen mas tamaño, que la cantidad de posiciones que tus arrays, recuerda que su posicion comienza en 0.

Answer (score 2):

> **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 java.lang.NullPointerException:** significa que estas tratamdo de accesar a un elemento de tu array que esta fuera de los límites.

Por ejemplo:

```
int [] array = new int[10]; // este array tiene 10 posiciones de la 0 a la 9
array[10]; // trato de acceder a la posición 10 (siendo la 9 la última), entonces esto es un error de compilación ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Según veo hay algo raro en tu código que podría darte el error que te mencioné y es en la línea 31(En el for de SILLAS_ECONOMICAS), según veo estás iterando en base al array de `sillasEconómicas` y en este caso estas tratando de acceder al array de `sillasEjecutivas`. No debería de ser de la siguiente manera?:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SILLAS_ECONOMICAS; i++){
   if(sillasEconomicas[i].sillaAsignada()){
       for(int j = 0; j < SILLAS_ECONOMICAS; j++){
           if(sillasEconomicas[j].sillaAsignada()){
               if(sillasEconomicas[i].darNumero() != sillasEconomicas[j].darNumero()){
                  if(darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEconomicas[i].darPasajero()) >= darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEconomicas[j].darPasajero())){
                     mayorSillasEjecutivas = sillasEjecutivas[i].darPasajero();
                     economicas = darNumSillasAsignadasPasajero(sillasEconomicas[i].darPasajero());
                  }
               }  
           }
       }
   }

}
```

En lugar de esta línea:

```
if(sillasEjecutivas[j].sillaAsignada())
```

Usar esto:

```
if(sillasEconomicas[j].sillaAsignada())
```

Espero te haya ayudado :)

Comment: Efectivamente  ya lo corregí pero me lanza el siguiente error:                           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 
java.lang.NullPointerException